# Min/Max over numbers and strings in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a long dataset and would like to get min/max values in a row:

```
    County   Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4
1   Autauga  54660   55253   51253   56253
```

Output should look like

```
    County   Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4   Min     Max    Max-Min
1   Autauga  54660   55253   51253   56253   51253   56253  5000
```

My first shot yielded a string as max value (I've read about all the reasons on the forum):

```
df['Max'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

1) How can I exclude my first column so the max function runs correctly (I still need the county in my output)?

2) How can I run the max,min functions AND calc the difference of each value in one go?

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify that you only want to do it on numerical elements.

```
df['Max'] = df.max(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
df['Min'] = df.min(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
df['Max - Min'] = df['Max'] - df['Min']

# if you only need "Max - Min"
df['Max - Min'] = df.max(1, numeric_only=True) - df.min(1, numeric_only=True)
```

By default, `max` function will try to use everything. With the extra argument, it will only includes columns that contains floats, int, and boolean values in the calculation. Read more about it at [`DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this done with a little `iloc` slicing magic.

```
df['Max'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].max(axis=1)
df['Min'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].min(axis=1)
df['Max - Min'] = df['Max'] - df['Min']
```

```
df    
    County  Year1  Year2  Year3  Year4    Max    Min  Max - Min
1  Autauga  54660  55253  51253  56253  56253  51253       5000
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [43]: df = df.assign(**{'Max-Min':df.max(1)-df.min(1)})

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
    County  Year1  Year2  Year3  Year4  Max-Min
1  Autauga  54660  55253  51253  56253     5000
```

Comment: Could you tell me does the double aster ** does?

Comment: @Tai, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: @Tai, you are welcome. I thought it would be too much for a comment, so i decided to give you a link to the comprehensive answer...

Comment: Sure sure. I thought it was something specific to pandas at first, but I now I know.